# Onload Event is blocking the execution of the call stack? UX is really choppy and not smooth

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am struggling to debug this code, I have an onload event of 352ms, when I scroll everything is choppy, and I want it to be smooth like other sites, but some part of the code is blocking the rest and i cant figure out what. Can you please help?

```
// Cache DOM elements
let $window = $(window);
let $document = $(document);
let $nav = $(".sticky-nav");
let $cell = $("#cell");
let $img = $(".img-1");
let $title = $("#title");

// debounce function
function debounce(func) {
  let timeout;

  return function () {
    const context = this;
    const args = arguments;

    const later = function () {
      timeout = null;
      func.apply(context, args);
    };

    if (timeout) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(timeout);
    }

    timeout = requestAnimationFrame(later);
  };
}

// NAV SCROLL FUNCTION
function handleScroll() {
  const scrollPos = $window.scrollTop();
  const windowWidth = $(window).width();

  if (scrollPos > 100) {
    $nav
      .addClass("has-bar")
      .css({ backgroundColor: "#8992A1", borderBottom: "2px solid silver" });
    $cell.css("color", "whitesmoke");

    // Check if the window width is <= 600px
    if (windowWidth <= 600) {
      $(".links").css({
        "background-color": "#8992A1",
        "border-left": "1px silver solid", // Adds the desired border
        "border-right": "1px silver solid",
        "border-bottom": "1px silver solid",
      });
    }

    if ($window.innerWidth() === 830) {
      $img.css("transform", "translateY(-3.4rem) scale(0.677777778)");
    } else {
      $img.css("transform", "translateY(-1.4rem) scale(0.677777778)");
    }
  } else {
    $nav.removeClass("has-bar").css({
      backgroundColor: "rgba(1000, 1000, 1000, 0)",
      borderBottom: "0px solid grey",
    });
    $cell.css("color", "silver");
    $img.css("transform", "translateY(0rem) scale(1)");
    $(".links").css({
      "background-color": "",
      "border-left": "",
      "border-right": "",
      "border-bottom": "",
    }); // Removes the border
  }

  if (scrollPos > 100) {
    $title.css({ transition: "opacity 200ms ease-in-out", opacity: "0" });
  } else {
    $title.css({ transition: "opacity 2s ease-in-out", opacity: "1" });
  }
}

if ($("body").is("#homepage")) {
  // If it does, run the function
  $window.on("scroll", debounce(handleScroll, 10));
}
handleScroll();

// adjust debounce time as required
// initial call

$(document).on("mouseenter", ".grid-video", function () {
  $(this).addClass("hovered");
  $(".grid-video").not(this).addClass("shrinked");
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".grid-video", function () {
  $(this).removeClass("hovered");
  $(".grid-video").removeClass("shrinked");
});

// Modal & other events
$(function () {
  let $popup = $("#popup");
  let $blurry = $("#blurry-effect");

  $("#quote-item").click(function () {
    $popup.add($blurry).css("display", "block");
  });

  $(".close").click(function () {
    $popup.add($blurry).css("display", "none");
  });

  $window.click(function (event) {
    if (event.target == $popup[0]) {
      $popup.add($blurry).css("display", "none");
    }
  });

  // Prevent default context menu for images and videos
  $document.on("contextmenu", function (e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === "IMG" || e.target.nodeName === "VIDEO") {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});

// ON LOAD FUNCTION
window.onload = async function () {
  let $logo = $(".img-1");
  let $cell = $("#cell");
  let $navItems = $(".li-item");
  let $arrow = $("#scroll-down-arrow");
  let $title = $("#title");

  $logo.css("opacity", ".9");
  $navItems.css("opacity", "0"); // set initial opacity to 0

  setTimeout(function () {
    $navItems.add($cell).css("opacity", "1"); // transition opacity to 1 after 1000ms
    $arrow.addClass("blink");
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function () {
    $title.css("opacity", "1");
  }, 1500);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
      $(".links").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $(".links").fadeOut();
    }
  });

  $("#hamburger").click(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
      if ($(".links").is(":visible")) {
        $(".links").slideUp();
      } else {
        $(".links").slideDown();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I'm not sure how to debug this, I tried adding the debounce function and caching DOM elements, but I think either one of my transitions is really screwed the way im handling it or something isnt async that needs to be. any help is appreciated.